# A reference for smooth structures on R^n

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, reference-request

There is a theorem stating that there is essentially one smooth structure on $R^n$ for every n other than 4. Does anybody know where i could find the proof of this? Not so much of what happens in dimension four, where there are infinitely many, but of the uniqueness in other dimensions? Thanks!

Comment: See also the answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24930/differentiable-structures-on-r3

Comment: For the high-dimensional case, a key part of the proof is the uniqueness of smooth structures on compact discs, which you get from the h-cobordism theorem.  skupers's answer gets you there.

Answer (score 14):

For $n \geq 5$ , this was first proven in Stallings' [The piecewise-linear structure of Euclidean space](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/stallings2.pdf). It actually proves the PL case and applies smoothing theory. Anyway, Theorem 5.1 of it says

> Let $M^n$ be a contractible differentiable manifold which is 1-connected at infinity. If $n \geq 5$, then $M$ is diffeomorphic to Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

A related result appears in Lashof's [ICM address](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.2/Main/icm1970.2.0091.0094.ocr.pdf) on smoothing theory. His Corollary says

> Every contractible open topological manifold is smoothable.

and he follows by remarking that this smooth structure is unique if $n \geq 5$.

For $n = 2,3$, there is Moise, but his articles may be hard to read. There are now easier proofs using Kirby-Siebenmann techniques. For $n = 2$, one can use Hatcher's [The Kirby torus trick for surfaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3518). For $n = 3$, one can use Hamilton's [The triangulation of 3-manifolds](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/hamiltontri.pdf) in the PL case and apply smoothing theory.

Answer (score 12):

You can handle the case of $n \leq 3$ one at a time, and so the question really is about $n \geq 5$. Two important names in this regard are Kirby and Siebenmann. The Wikipedia article on the [Hauptvermutung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung) is a good place to start.

If M is an $n$-dimensional topological manifold (and $n \geq 5$), then $M$ admits a PL structure if and only if a special cohomology class, the Kirby-Siebenmann class, in $H^4(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ vanishes. If this class vanishes, then the different PL structures are parametrized up to concordance by $H^3(M; \mathbb{Z})$. (Note: The Wikipedia article on the Hauptvermutung assumes that $M$ is compact, but I don't believe that this is a necessary assumption.)

So what does this say about $M = \mathbb{R}^n$? Well, we already know that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a PL structure, and since $H^3(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{Z}_2)=0$, it follows that this structure is unique up to concordance. Since concordance implies diffeomorphism, and since every smooth structure gives us a PL structure, it follows that there can be only one smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ up to diffeomorphism.

Here are the main references (you can find them both [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/haupt/)):

1. Kirby and Siebenmann, On the triangulation of manifolds and the Hauptvermutung.  Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.  75  1969 742--749.
2. Kirby and Siebenmann, Foundational essays on topological manifolds, smoothings, and triangulations. Annals of Mathematics Studies 88 (1977). (I did some MathSciNet investigating, and the relevant essays are IV and V.)

[This](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AT/0105047) expository article by Rudyak, which I found through Wikipedia, also seems interesting.

Finally, I learned all of this from Scorpan's wonderful book, "The Wild World of 4-Manifolds".

Answer (score 9):

S. K. Donaldson and P. B. Kronheimer. The geometry of four-
manifolds. Clarendon Press, New York, 1990.

Michael Freedman and Frank Quinn. Topology of 4-manifolds.
Princeton University Press, Princeton, 1990.

These are recommended by Lee in his "Topology of Smooth Manifolds"

Edwin E. Moise. Geometric Topology in Dimensions 2 and 3.
Springer-Verlag, New York, 1977.

James R. Munkres. Obstructions to the smoothing of piecewise
differentiable homeomorphisms. Annals of Math., 72:521–554,
1960.

These are also recommended by Lee as proving the R^n (except for 4) claim.

I personally have not read them, but I, for now, trust Lee's judgement.

Comment: Do any of these references discuss uniqueness of smooth structures on R^n for n>4?

Comment: This is not quite an answer to the question.  Only the Moise and Munkres references are to answers.